# AttributeError: 'Thread1' object has no attribute '_initialized'

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

well i got this problem when trying to stop a thread with the .join method

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    t1.alto()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Phyton\Thread1.py", line 16, in alto
    t1.join()
AttributeError: 'Thread1' object has no attribute '_initialized'
```

Here is my Thread1 module:

```
import threading

class Thread1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):

        print('Entre al hilo')

    def corre(self):
        x = 10
        for i in range (1, 11,1):
            val = x*i
            print(val, '% completado')

    def alto(self):
        t1.join()

t1 = Thread1()
```

Finally, this is how I call the Thread1 module:

```
if(lista[0] == 'A'):
    self.p1.set('Procesando')
    t1.corre()
    lista.remove('A')
    self.p1.set('Espera')
```

Comment: I don't know what implementation of `threading` you are using but in most implementations you need to override __init__ and run() in your thread child class and then use inst.start() on your instance. Although corre may be a word for run I'm not sure that there are any implementations of the `threading` module that actually use that word.

Comment: im using 3.4, corre its just the name of the function, which suppose to do like a percentage of the progress, so on my child class i was just calling to that function

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to call the constructor (**init**) of the superclass:

```
class Thread1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Entre al hilo')
    ...
```

Secondly, the code you want to run in a separate thread must be put in a method called `run`:

```
    def run(self):
        # code to be run in separate thread
```

Thirdly, to start the separate thread, call `start`:

```
t1.start()
# the code in run() will now be run in parallell with whatever follows here.
```

The reason for your error is that you have not actually started the separate thread (with `start()`), thus there is no thread to `join()` with.

Also, since you have no `run()` method, even if you call `start()` nothing will be run in the thread.

Comment: Thanks oyvind, where should i call start?

Comment: `start()` starts the thread, so you call it when you want the thread to start, i.e. when you want the code in `run` to start executing (in parallel with your other code).